# Extract row that immediately precedes new instance of grouping variable

Tags: r, dplyr

From this type of data:

```
df <- data.frame(
  IPU_id = 1:9,
  Sequ = c(NA,NA,1,1,2,2,NA,3,3),
  Q = c(NA,NA,"q_wh","q_wh","q_wh","q_wh",NA,"q_pol","q_pol"),
  N_extension = c(NA,NA,0,NA,1,NA,NA,0,NA)
)
```

I'd like to extract for each distinct `Sequ` the immediately preceding row regardless of whether `Sequ` in that row `is.na(Sequ)` or a positive `Sequ` value. The desired result is this:

```
df
  IPU_id Sequ     Q N_extension
2      2   NA  <NA>          NA
4      4    1  q_wh          NA
7      7   NA  <NA>          NA
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you need to find the rows where the following row has a different value of `Sequ` (`(Sequ != lead(Sequ)`), including the case where `Sequ` is `NA` but not the following row (`is.na(Sequ) & !is.na(lead(Sequ))`):

```r
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(
  IPU_id = 1:9,
  Sequ = c(NA,NA,1,1,2,2,NA,3,3),
  Q = c(NA,NA,"q_wh","q_wh","q_wh","q_wh",NA,"q_pol","q_pol"),
  N_extension = c(NA,NA,0,NA,1,NA,NA,0,NA)
)

df |> 
  filter(
    (Sequ != lead(Sequ)) | 
      (is.na(Sequ) & !is.na(lead(Sequ)))
  )
#>   IPU_id Sequ    Q N_extension
#> 1      2   NA <NA>          NA
#> 2      4    1 q_wh          NA
#> 3      7   NA <NA>          NA
```

<sup>Created on 2023-05-01 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Since the operation in your `mutate` already returns boolean values, I guess you can use that directly in a single `filter` as in `df %>% filter((Sequ != lead(Sequ)) | (is.na(Sequ) & !is.na(lead(Sequ))))`. Good answer +1!

Answer (score 1):

First find the row indices for each `distinct` `Sequ` that is not `NA`, then use it to index the original `df`.

```r
library(tidyverse)

df[(df %>% mutate(rn = row_number()) %>% drop_na(Sequ) %>% distinct(Sequ, .keep_all = T) %>% pull(rn)) - 1,]

  IPU_id Sequ    Q N_extension
2      2   NA <NA>          NA
4      4    1 q_wh          NA
7      7   NA <NA>          NA
```